# Python sqlite3 error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def menuAdiciona():
    nome = input("Digite o nome de quem fez o cafe: ")
    nota = int(input("Que nota recebeu: "))

    if len(str(nome).strip()) == 0:
        menuAdiciona()

    if (nota) == 0:
        menuAdiciona()

    if nota < 0:
        nota = 0
```

appears this:

> Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: the input from the user is considered a string, therefore converting it to an int should work OK. Can you please give the rest of the output regarding the error.

Comment: Mostly this error is seen when you try to concatenate a string and an integer: for e.g : `'1' + 1` --> `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`, so check your code for such mistakes.

Comment: print (today)
sql = ("INSERT INTO cafe () VALUES ('"+nome+"','"+nota+"','"+data+"')")
 cursor.execute(sql)
 cursor.commit()
 geraMenu()

this is the rest

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you provided "works" in Python 2.7 and 3.

A line number or stacktrace would be helpful, but assuming it's in the snippet you provided:

```
nota = int(input("Que nota recebeu: "))
```

Here `nota` is an int.

```
if len(str(nome).strip()) == 0:
```

The next line you're trying to cast it to a string without specifying how.

Something like:

```
if len(("%d" % nota).strip()) == 0:
```

should prevent the error.

That being said, the line still makes little sense.  You shouldn't have to `strip()` a string representation of an integer.

What are you trying to accomplish with `strip()` and the `if len(...) == 0` parts?

Edit:  Lastly, I think you want `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, unless you're shadowing that somewhere too.

Comment: Hey jedwards can you send me an email?
I think its more easy send you all my program and you look all.
Please, if you have time.
isaias_duarte7@hotmail.com